# Why does my jquery loop give an incorrect comparison of values from two arrays?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, for-loop

I have two arrays...

```
var arr3 = [];
$('td:nth-child(2)').each(function() {
    arr3.push($(this).text());
});
//console.log(arr3);

var arr4 = [];
$('td:nth-child(6)').each(function() {
    arr4.push($(this).text());
});
//console.log(arr4);
```

These gather up some data I want in a chart. My goal is to compare the two arrays to see if the value in arr3 is greater than or equal to the value in arr4, for each given position.

Yesterday everything seemed to be working, but tonight I changed the data a bit and now it's saying something is true that isn't.

```
arr3 = ["0", "0", "30"]
arr4 = ["150", "150", "140"]
```

So `0 < 150`, `0 < 150` and it should be `30 < 140` but instead my loop says `30 >= 140`.

Here's my loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr3.length; i++) {
    if (arr3[i] >= arr4[i]) {
        console.log(arr3[i] + " is >= " + arr4[i]);
        var bearned2 = $('.g2bonus')[i];
        $(bearned2).append(' ✔');
    } else {
        console.log(arr3[i] + " is < " + arr4[i]);
    }
}
```

I tried to research this and found out about closure errors, but I couldn't quite understand it and couldn't apply a proper fix to my situation. I tried this loop but it only reports the first comparison and not the other two:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr3.length; arr3++) {
    (function(index) {
        if (arr3[i] >= arr4[i]) {
            console.log(arr3[i] + " is >= " + arr4[i]);
            var bearned2 = $('.g2bonus')[i];
            $(bearned2).append(' ✔');
        } else {
            console.log(arr3[i] + " is < " + arr4[i]);
        }
    })(i);
}
```

Any help on this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert your string representation of numbers within your arrays to integers/numbers so that your inequalities work correctly. As:

`"30" >= "140"` is *true*

but

`30 >= 140` is *false*.

To do this you can simply just add a `+` in front of a string representing a number to convert it to a number (integer, float, etc...)

See working example below:

```js
var arr3 = ["0", "0", "30", "100"];
var arr4 = ["150", "150", "140", "0"];

for (var i = 0; i < arr3.length; i++) {
  if (+arr3[i] >= +arr4[i]) { // Add + infront of arr3[i] and arr4[i] to convert to numbers
    console.log(arr3[i] + " is >= " + arr4[i]);
    var bearned2 = $('.g2bonus')[i];
    $(bearned2).append(' ✔');
  } else {
    console.log(arr3[i] + " is < " + arr4[i]);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Also, I've added another check at the end to show that it won't output *false* for every value and that your check is working (`100 >= 0` is *true*)